# Has Staphylococcus aureus ever been used against cancer?

Tags: microbiology, cancer

Treating inoperable tumors with bacteria appears to be very effective, albeit being toxic to the patient as well. Has (live attenuated) *Staphylococcus aureus* ever been used against cancer? If the answer is yes, can you give me a link to some papers on this topic as well?

Comment: Amy sources to your claim?  I've never heard of using bacteria against cancer?!

Comment: @Christiaan I actually interviewed recently at a company that's doing just that. It's really interesting.

Comment: Is OP talking about Coley's toxins? http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/cancers-in-general/cancer-questions/coleys-toxins-cancer-treatment and Streptococcus pyogenes and Serratia marcescens are currently used, not Staph.